# How to perform roll-out of an RNN In pytorch

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I trained an RNN (a GRU to be specific) to be a language model roughly as follows:

```python
inputs = [<start>, tok1, tok2, tok3, . . .]

outputs = [tok1, tok2, tok3, . . .]

h0 = initial state of all-zeros

gru_outputs, hn = gru(inputs, h0)

cost = loss (gru_outputs, outputs)
```

Essentially during training there is a "guide" input, where I feed in the **target** token from the last-step to the current-step (teacher forcing?).

Now this RNN trains well, and converges. But I have no idea how to actually **use** it to generate a sequence from scratch. As the gru expect an explicit input argument, how do I tell it to use its own output from the last step without giving it an input?

Essentially I want

```python
roll_out = gru(h0, step_number = 10)
```

Couldn't quite figure out how to do this. Do I need to use a different API and do manual roll-out in both training and using?

full-code in this gist if it is of any use: https://gist.github.com/evanthebouncy/b5039dc72d3d9fea66dad3306e479e6b

thanks !

--evan

Comment: So you are training a language model, but you don't know how to create a text sequence with the trained model?

Comment: yep. any help? 1char

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to test your language model by generating random text - just pick a random token as first word. After feeding this random word the model will generate an output, then this word you just generated will be your next input which you feed into the model and so on.

Here is some sample code how this could look like:

```py
# Test the model
with torch.no_grad():
    with open('sample.txt', 'w') as f:
        # Set intial hidden ane cell states
        state = (torch.zeros(num_layers, 1, hidden_size).to(device),
                 torch.zeros(num_layers, 1, hidden_size).to(device))

        # Select one word id randomly
        prob = torch.ones(vocab_size)
        input = torch.multinomial(prob, num_samples=1).unsqueeze(1).to(device)

        for i in range(num_samples):
            # Forward propagate RNN 
            output, state = model(input, state)

            # Sample a word id
            prob = output.exp()
            word_id = torch.multinomial(prob, num_samples=1).item()

            # Fill input with sampled word id for the next time step
            input.fill_(word_id)

            # File write
            word = corpus.dictionary.idx2word[word_id]
            word = '\n' if word == '<eos>' else word + ' '
            f.write(word)

            if (i+1) % 100 == 0:
                print('Sampled [{}/{}] words and save to {}'.format(i+1, num_samples, 'sample.txt'))
```

*Full code also for the model can be found [here](https://github.com/yunjey/pytorch-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/02-intermediate/language_model/main.py#L90).*

You might need to modify the code a bit so that it works for your model.

Comment: this function you are using, "model", what does it take? It takes a single input and a single hidden state right? That's exactly my problem. The code I'm training, "gru", takes in a _sequence_ of input, NOT a single token. I don't know how to get the trained-model to perform a single-step computation.

my work around was just to keep appending to the inputs (note, _inputs_, with an s) array and re-compute the outputs each time, which is horribly inefficient. I was asking how to deal with this problem.

Comment: You can put in whatever sequence length you want to, the model has no restriction on that. What is fixed after creation of the model is just the input dim.